# Flutter: Design this type of FL_CHART line chart

Tags: flutter, dart, linechart

[image: line chart]

```
return LineChart(
  LineChartData(
      gridData: FlGridData(
        show: false,
      ),
      titlesData: FlTitlesData(
        show: true,
        bottomTitles: SideTitles(
          showTitles: true,
          reservedSize: 14,
          getTitles: (value) {
            return _months[value.toInt()];
          },
        ),
        leftTitles: SideTitles(
          showTitles: true,
          getTitles: (value) {
            return (value.toInt()).toString();
          },
          interval: 180/10,
          reservedSize: 28,
          margin: 12,
        ),
      ),
      borderData: FlBorderData(show: false),
      minX: 0,
      minY: 0,
      lineBarsData: [
        LineChartBarData(spots: [
          FlSpot(1, 10),
          FlSpot(2, 50),
          FlSpot(3, 99),
          FlSpot(4, 45),
          FlSpot(5, 130),
          FlSpot(6, 180),

        ], isCurved: true,
barWidth: 5,
isStrokeCapRound: true,
          belowBarData: BarAreaData(
            show: true,
            colors: [Colors.yellow, Colors.red],
            gradientColorStops: [0, 0.1, 0.2],
            gradientFrom: const Offset(1, 1),
            // gradientTo: const Offset(0, 1),
          ),
        )
      ]),
);
```

Can anyone help me to design this type of line chart with the shadows as on the image

Comment: Please post what you have done so far, where are you stuck?

Comment: @HuthaifaMuayyad Ok